# R gsub regular expression syntax error

Tags: r

If I have some string : 2017-01-12T19:00:00.000+000, and I want to have 2017-01-12, so delete all after and including  "T" How do I proceed,

```
gsub("$.*T"," ","2017-01-12T19:00:00.000+000")
```

, would this not work? I am referring my self to:http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/gsub.php

Thank you!

Comment: `"T.+$"` I think you want. `$` represents the end of the entire string so nothing is going to work with what you have.

Comment: Extracting date time with regex can be quite risky. Try to convert it in the standard format and then extract the information that you need. Try `as.POSIXct("2017-01-12T19:00:00.000+000")` Or `as.Date("2017-01-12T19:00:00.000+000")`

Comment: `substr("2017-01-12T19:00:00.000+000", 1, 10)` but all the comments above should be noted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to match and capture the date portion of your string using `gsub()` and then replace the entire string with what was captured.

```
gsub("(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}).*","\\1","2017-01-12T19:00:00.000+000")
[1] "2017-01-12"
```

Your original approach:

```
gsub("T.*","","2017-01-12T19:00:00.000+000")
[1] "2017-01-12"
```

As others have said, if the need for this format exceeds the scope of this particular timestamp string, then you should consider using a date API instead.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: removed comment